# Cannot create a new Timestamp column in pandas based on a conditional w/np.where

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

In the process of writing out a script to automate the compilation of a report, I'm trying to create a column of Timestamps based on a conditional using np.where(). The logic is as follows:

```
df['StartMonth'] = np.where(
    chng['Count'] == 1, pd.Timestamp(
        int(year), chng['Month'].astype(int), 1), str('')
    )
```

The DataFrame is a list of employees who are either considered additions or deletions, where the `chng['Count']` is used as a flag that shows +1 as an addition and -1 as a deletion. So where any employee is being added, create the `StartMonth` series where the fixed `year` variable, the `Month` of the row, and `1` are used as the basis to create the timestamp (both `year` and chng['Month'] are strings, hence casting them as integers in the conditional). The output of the function comes up as the following for each `True` row:

```
   Month  Count                              StartMonth
0      1      1  1970-01-01 00-00-01.000002+00019:00:01
1      1      1  1970-01-01 00-00-01.000002+00019:00:01
2      4      1  1970-01-01 00-00-01.000002+00019:00:01
3      5      1  1970-01-01 00-00-01.000002+00019:00:01
4     10      1  1970-01-01 00-00-01.000002+00019:00:01
```

I've tried this with `year` and chng['Month'] already cast as integers prior to the conditional and it's been the same result. The only time it "works" is when chng['Month'] is replaced with any other arbitrary number, leading me to believe that is the issue. I have done plenty of other conditionals with np.where() that use values from another Series in the DataFrame (though not as the base for a Timestamp creation) without any problem, so I'm not sure what is causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1. You should use `pd.to_datetime` for **vectorised** conversion, rather than `pd.Timestamp`.
2. `numpy.where` returns a NumPy array, which is not the same as a Pandas `datetime` series. But you can feed an array to `pd.to_datetime`.
3. You should avoid combining strings with `datetime` values in a single series. Choose one. Here, instead of `''` use `pd.NaT` to ensure your series remains `datetime`.

Here's an example solution:

```
year = 2018
s = str(year) + '-' + df['Month'].astype(str)

df['StartMonth'] = pd.to_datetime(np.where(df['Count'] == 1, s, pd.NaT))

print(df)

   Month  Count StartMonth
0      1      1 2018-01-01
1      1      1 2018-01-01
2      4      1 2018-04-01
3      5      1 2018-05-01
4     10      1 2018-10-01
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! Works like a charm. I'll have to be more careful with `numpy` functions as it relates to Pandas' `datetime`. I feel like I'm still getting my head around the differences between that and the standard Python `datetime` as well.